# AngularJS - Creating shorthand routes with $route.routes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-routing

[**Plnkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/30t53evpojKu2vkegGrL?p=preview)

I am migrating AngularJS from 1.1.5 to 1.2.27. In the older version, I was able to use shorthand routes i.e.,

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
   $routeProvider
     .when('/show/:list/:type', {templateUrl: 'product.html', controller: 'product_controller'})
     .otherwise({redirectTo: '/show/product'});
}]);

app.controller('app_controller', ['$route', function($route){
   $route.routes['/show/product'] = {
      redirecTo: 'show/product/active'
   };
   $route.routes['/show/user'] = {
      redirecTo: 'show/user/active'
   };
}]);
```

In the above code, when the user enter a url as 'show/product', it redirects to the route 'show/product/active' which was happening in 1.1.5 but this doesn't seems to be works in 1.2.X.

Do you have any idea, why it is not working?

I have a solution in my mind,

```
app.run(['$rootScope', function($rootScope){
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(event, current_route, previous_route){
       //do the conditional redirection using $location.path();
    }
}]);
```

Does this idea looks meaningful and will it work, any suggestion or help?

Comment: `redirecTo != redirectTo`

Comment: I've written that code myself before creating the plnkr. Its a typo and you can check the Plnkr that I have updated few mins back.